# Can't access array from within protractor callback

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm new to both protractor and javascript. I ran into a scoping issue which I can't figure out. In the code segment below, the first array access statement works but the second doesn't. What gives?

```
for(var i=0;i<=1;i++){
    console.log(msgs[i]);
    element.all(by.className("form-group")).get(i).element(by.className("alert alert-danger")).getText().then(function(txt){                
        console.log(msgs[i]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change

```
... .getText().then(function(txt){ ... });
```

to

```
... .getText().then((txt) => { ... });
```

It's called [fat arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and it does not have it's own `this` so you can access your array.