# Variable scope in protractor

Tags: scope, jasmine, protractor

I am running protractor and jasmine to run unit tests.

I need to know the build version of my web app in order to execute different tests.

I have declared a variable to store this version value.

```
var version ='';
```

I am getting the version number by using the following code.

```
menuObject.modaltext.getText().then(function(text) {
            version = text.slice(79,86);
            console.log(version);
            browser.driver.sleep(7000);
});
```

The version number is acquired correctly and is consoled properly.

But when i use this version outside of this .then function, its value becomes undefined and I am unable to check for any conditions using that variable.

How can i access the version number so that I use it to control the flow of the tests.

![version variable is highlighted, I am unable to access the version inside the if cases]

[image]

Comment: Where are you declaring it?

Comment: Just inside the describe

Comment: And this code snippet is in your it spec? May be you can also paste the complete describe block as well if it's that big?

Comment: I will paste the code within 15 minutes

Comment: Sir, I have edited the original post

Comment: what if you use `this.version`?

Comment: Same thing happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174734/discussion-between-edupeeth-and-sharath-prakash).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208375/cant-access-array-from-within-protractor-callback/51252834#51252834

Comment: @Batajus   No sir, it is not. Different use cases and the solution in your question didn't work for me.

Comment: @SharathPrakash, you are trying to use version outside specs. What happens is that specs haven't executed or your variable isn't initialized yet and your code outside your spec executes and prints `undefined`. Now, I would like to understand as why would you like to put code outside your specs in a protractor test. Could you please share your requirement that asks you to do it this way?

Comment: @Edupeeth I need version outside of my specs in order to perform a check and only execute specific "it" modules. Lets say if version was X then IT1, IT2 and IT3 will run. If version was Y then IT1 and IT2 will run not IT3. Is there any way to do this? I need that version to be accessible outside the specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `var` to `let`. This allows to access your `version` inside your specs.

```
describe('Nodeprojectpart2Component', () => {
    let version = '';
    beforeEach(() => {
        version = '1.0';
      });

    it('test', () => {
      console.log( 'version' + version);
    });

  });
```

Issue with your code - Your are retrieving the value of version inside an asynchronous/callback function. Now before your function executes, your console is executed and prints `undefined`. I am not sure why would you like to define code outside specs. But if you still want to, you shall have the retrieval logic right after you define it in `desribe` block, something like -

```
describe('Nodeprojectpart2Component', () => {
        let version = '';
        version = //logic to find the version here itself
        ....
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for the solution. I will try it out and will let you know